# Transparent button in API 8 and forward

Tags: android, button, transparency

Im stuck on trying to get some buttons to be transparent in older API's.
In ICS and forward I can use `setAlpha(0);` but that wont work in the older once. 
How can I set the buttons transparent in API 8-10?

Comment: Umm, set the background to `null`?

Comment: is there way to set color to #00xxxxxx where x-es represent color? (first two digits are alpha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set background to null

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:background="@null"/>
```

Or in code

```
button.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

or

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Or you can define a style for a button in your theme so all buttons will have null background by default

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/NoBackgroundButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="NoBackgroundButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Have no xml for these. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply alpha to the whole button on older Android versions, you can use [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library, with its ViewHelper class. For example:

```
    ViewHelper.setAlpha(someView, someAlphaValue);
```